# How do I tell if exactly N conditions in a set of M conditions are true in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

The title is a bit confusing, so I'll give an example. Say I have a set of 4 conditions, [A,B,C,D], where each condition can either be true or false. For example, condition A can either say

```
A[i,j+1] == 0
```

or

```
A[i,j+1] != 0
```

I want an if statement that essentially says the following:

```
if (in [A,B,C,D], any 2 are true and any 2 are false):
    do something
else:
    do something else
```

I could hard-code each individual case if necessary. For example:

```
if ((A and B are true) and (C and D are false)) or  ((A and C are true) and (B and D are false)) or...
```

and I can just continue that for every possible case. However, that seems wildly inefficient and not pythonic.

What's the best method to do this? Should I just hard-code it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So A,B,C,D are either `True` `False` or 0s and 1s?

Comment: @ombk yes. Just figured out you can use sum([conditions]) = N to solve the problem I had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering `[A,B,C,D]` are either `binary` or `booleans`, you can use the sum function.

`True=1` `False=0` in the sum.

```
if sum([A,B,C,D])==2:
    'do something'
```

Comment: What do you mean with `binary`?

Comment: @superbrain just `0`s and `1`s . not the cmps meaning :p

Comment: @Stephen accept the answer to avoid reappearing in feed

Comment: @ombk Yeah, I still have to wait 3 minutes because I don't have enough reputation to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sum()`, this works because `True = 1` and `False = 0` so `True+True+False+False=1+1+0+0=2`, but one problem is any value except 0/None evaluate to True, so if something inside A,B,C,D is -1 or other it will fail ;-(

```
if sum([A,B,C,D]) == 2:
    # 2 False, 2 True
```

A bit shorter but non geeky way:

```
if A+B+C+D == 2:
    # 2 False, 2 True
```